# After doing chroot , a copy of nodejs inside jail do not launches node console?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chroot

I am trying to run nodejs from a jailed system using chroot.
This is where I wanted my jail [mnt/mylinux] :
[image: chroot jail]
bash and all its dependencies [found using `ldd`] are copied to correct folders in jail.
I copied nodejs in bin folder as such:

[image: node folder destination]

Then I also copied all dependency required for node [using `ldd`].
Now when I chroot and then try and invoke node it does not opens its console ?
[image]

without chrooting the node is working perfectly fine.
[image]

I have copied all the dependencies required for node in my jail.
So why after creating jail, nodejs do not launches its console ?

Comment: Do not use screen shots. Type the text here. Shall we read and type instead of copy and paste from your question?

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't just use nvm?

Comment: @RobotHumans Actually I am experimenting to create a OS with default shell as Nodejs REPL. My Kernel will boot with init process as `node`. My experiment was successful using a python shell. But node seems to not launch from a jail.

Comment: I highly recommend against that, but at least I understand your motivations.  The JS guy that used to work with me and got all the patterns in place then couldn't handle his business went with "Yeah, we should have used python for this like you said.  I didn't realize we were performing a synchronous task", but win some lose some.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously something necessary is missing e.g.

- `/proc`
- `/sys/`
- `/dev`
- `/dev/pts`

Running the file through `strace` may show what the problem is.

Comment: I ran strace, it seems to be running in loops printing log list of logs which is never stopping, which might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: @user3769778 That's not the cause but the symptom. The cause is hidden somewhere in the loop. If it is too long then searching for the cause is probably not much fun. What you are looking for is a syscall with an error exit code. Probably open() or lstat(). You could copy the whole loop to a file and filter away all lines with ` = 0` and check the open() calls. Have you created bind mounts of the directories I mention in my answer?

Answer (score -1):

```
mount --bind /dev $chroot/dev

mount --bind /proc $chroot/proc
```

then it does work!

thank you Hauke Laging

Comment: It is better if you also explain, why does it make working (console device reachability).